# Is there a sense in which collections of probability distributions with the same matrix of Bhattacharyya coefficients are "essentially the same"?

Tags: experiment-design, signal-detection, bhattacharyya

A popular measure of "closeness" between probability distributions $\vec{p_1}$, $\vec{p_2}$ is the Bhattacharyya coefficient $\sum_j \sqrt{p_{1,j} p_{2,j}}$. Consider two statistical models $p(X|\Theta)$, $q(X|\Theta)$ with $\Theta\in \\\{1,\ldots, k\\\}$ finite, i.e. conditional probability distributions of some observation $X$ in dependence of the underlying parameter $\Theta$. Consider the $k\times k$ matrices of Bhattacharyya coefficients of these probability distributions. As I understand, matrix entries are related (by some inequalities) to the failure probability when we try to distinguish different values of $\Theta$ by sampling $X$. But is there a statement that this matrix is, in some sense, actually *sufficient* information to judge how much observing $X$ is helpful to learn something about $\Theta$? In other words, that the Bhattacharyya coefficient matrices of $p$ and $q$ are equal if and only if the maximum success probabilities/best achievable figures of merit for some class of distinguishing/learning tasks are equal, possibly asymptotically?